# Importing XML with .php extension

Tags: php, xml

I'm running into the following problem:

I have the following url link.php.
It is a php file but it should be used as XML. Now when I view the page source it shows me XML but I'm unable to import the data to my website.

I've tried the following methods:

```
1.    $objDOM = new DOMDocument();
    $test = $objDOM->load("link.php");


2.    $nodes = simplexml_load_file("link.php");


3.    $xml=simplexml_load_string('link.php') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
```

But unfortunately all the above functions return a false and I think it has to do with the .php extension.
Is it possible to import this file as XML?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I get prompted for username/password whn trying to access that url. That being the case your would probably either need to use curl and set the correct authorization header and then proceed to load the response into `DOMDocument`

Comment: "I think it has to do with the .php extension" — It doesn't. There is no such thing as a file extension in a URL. Just a content-type header.

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with XML. You're trying to download a password-protected resource form the internet and you don't make any attempt to authenticate. If you enable PHP error reporting, you'll possibly see a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. There is indeed a username and password. Think it was saved so it opened automatically in my browser. Is it possible to authenticate with php and then load with so I can publicate it on my server? (Without making username and password visible to users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I got it:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "link.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username' . ':' . 'password');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```

This provides me the right data. So like Quentin sayd, has nothing to do with extension but with authentification.

Thanks for all responses!